# Simple rest crud web service using JAX-RS, mysql, JSON, Jersey, Tomcat

Tags: java, mysql, web-services, rest, tomcat

I'm trying to create a simple restful web service that supports CRUD operations using Jersey, Tomcat 8.0, JAX-RS, mysql and JSON. I followed this guide (https://codezone4.wordpress.com/2012/11/08/restful-web-services-java-mysql-and-json/) and my result is the following:

[This is my project architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSvUL.png)

This is Party.java, the class that I use when I wanna bind data after querying database:

```
package dto;

public class Party {
private int id;
private String name;
private String organizer;
private String date;
private String place;

public Party(){

}

public Party(int id, String name, String organizer, String date, String place){
    super();
    this.id=id;
    this.name=name;
    this.organizer=organizer;
    this.date=date;
    this.place=place;
}

    public int getId()
    {
    return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id)
    {
    this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
    return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
    this.name = name;
    }

    public String getOrganizer()
    {
    return organizer;
    }

    public void setOrganizer(String organizer)
    {
    this.organizer = organizer;
    }

    public String getDate()
    {
    return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date)
    {
    this.date = date;
    }

    public String getPlace()
    {
    return place;
    }

    public void setPlace(String place)
    {
    this.place = place;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
    return "Party [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", organizer=" + organizer
    + ", date=" + date + "place=" + place + "]";
    }
}
```

This is Database.java:

```
package dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class Database {
    public Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
        try {
            String connectionURL = 
        "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myParty";
        Connection connection = null;
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "");
        return connection; 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
}
}
```

This is Access.java:

```
package dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import dto.Party;

public class Access {
public ArrayList<Party> getParties(Connection con) throws SQLException {
    ArrayList<Party> partyList = new ArrayList<Party>();
    PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM party");
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    try {
        while(rs.next()) {
            Party partyObj = new Party();
            partyObj.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            partyObj.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            partyObj.setOrganizer(rs.getString("organizer"));
            partyObj.setDate(rs.getString("date"));
            partyObj.setPlace(rs.getString("place"));
            partyList.add(partyObj);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return partyList;
}
}
```

This is AccessManager.java:

```
package model;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import dao.Access;
import dao.Database;
import dto.Party;

public class AccessManager {
public ArrayList<Party> getParties() throws Exception {
    ArrayList<Party> partyList = new ArrayList<Party>();
    Database db = new Database();
    Connection con = db.getConnection();
    Access access = new Access();
    partyList = access.getParties(con);
    return partyList;
}
}
```

This is PartyService.java:

```
package webService;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import model.AccessManager;

import dto.Party;

@Path("/partyService")
public class PartyService {
@GET
@Path("/parties")
@Produces("application/json")
public String parties() {
    String parties = null;
    ArrayList<Party> partyList = new ArrayList<Party>();
    try {
        partyList = new AccessManager().getParties();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        parties = gson.toJson(partyList);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return parties;
}
}
```

As you can see at the moment there is only the GET operation. I manually created in mysql under the root user a database called myParty, I created in it a table called party and I added one row of data in this table. If I type "SELECT * FROM party" it correctly returns that row. Than in theory the GET operation should return that row.

This is web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" 
version="3.0">
  <display-name>myParty_0.1</display-name>
  <servlet>
<servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
 <!-- Register resources and providers under com.vogella.jersey.first package. -->
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>myParty_0.1</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Now, in theory, if I run this project in the Tomcat server and I go to http:/ /localhost:8081/myParty_0.1/rest/partyService/parties (8081 is the Tomcat server port in my configuration), it should return the row that I added in the mysql table, but instead it returns "HTTP Status 404 - Not Found", "description: the request resource is not available". I tryed also with Google Postman doing a GET request: in HTML format it gives me the same error of the browser, in JSON format it says "Unexpected '<'". The Tomcat server is working than the problem is not Tomcat. I think that the error is in web.xml or in PartyService.java, or something in the mysql configuration considering that it says "resource not found". I have read my code many times but I have not found the problem, can someone help me please?

Comment: What is the name of you WAR? How about /localhost:8081/<WAR name here>/rest/partyService/parties ?

Comment: With WAR name you mean the project name in eclipse? In this case it is myParty_0.1 and the url is the same

Answer (score 2):

I've found the answer myself: the mistake was in web.xml, between the param-value tags. Here there must be the package that contains the resources class (in my case the class is PartyService.java, that's contained in the webService package), so if I change that row like this

```
<param-value>webService</param-value>
```

it works.